# Remove Form After Submit Jquery (JSP&Servlet)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp, servlets

I want To submit multiple form using Jquery (ALready done) but the problem is .. every time after submit i want the form is remove from list form Here's My JSP code

```
<form action="searchTweet" method="post">
    <textarea name="searchTxt"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="post" value="Search"/>

</form>
 <%
    if(session.getAttribute("twitModel")!=null)
    {

       List<TwitterModel> twit=(List<TwitterModel>)session.getAttribute("twitModel");

       int count=0;
       for(TwitterModel tweet:twit)
    {
           count=count+1;

%>
<p>
    @<%=tweet.getScreenName()%> : <%=tweet.getTweet() %>
   <form id="form2" method="post">
   <input type="hidden"  name="screenName" value="<%= tweet.getScreenName() %>">
   <input type="hidden"  name="tweet" value="<%= tweet.getTweet() %>">
   <input type="submit"  class="update_form" value="Save"> <!-- changed -->
   </form>
    </p>     <%   } }  %>
```

My Jquery for multiple submit form

```
   <script>
   // this is the class of the submit button
   $(".update_form").click(function() { // changed
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "saveSearch",
       data: $(this).parent().serialize(), // changed
       success: function(data)
       {
         $(this).parents('p').remove();
       }
     });
      return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong??

Thank's

Regards

Danz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `this` has changed to global `window` variable inside the `success` function, try this for once:

```
 $(".update_form").click(function() { // changed
    var me = this;
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "saveSearch",
       data: $(this).parent().serialize(), // changed
       success: function(data)
       {
         $(me).parents('p').remove();
       }
     });
      return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
   });
```

read up on [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: I've tried your solution but still no luck , its only submit the form but it didn't remove the submitted form from page..

Comment: Are you sure `success` function is getting called? try using `complete` instead of `success` option and also see what responseCode are you getting?

Comment: Using alert I'm print out the data ..If i'm using complete option it's print out xmlhttpRequest, and if i'm using success it show response from my servlet..

Comment: no problem at the server side then..did `closest` as suggested by Arun work? try `$('#form2').remove()` and if it does, replace with `$('#form2').parent().remove()`

Comment: Ok its work !! Thank's a a lot :). Just like u suggest to me, I'm using $('#form2').remove();

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the success handler refers to the ajax object, not the clicked button. In this case you can use a closure variable to fix the issue.

Also not the use of .closest() instead of .parents()

```
$(".update_form").click(function () { // changed
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "saveSearch",
        data: $(this).parent().serialize(), // changed
        success: function (data) {
            $this.closest('p').remove();
        }
    });
    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```